# Pagination is not working when query searched using search engine. What to do?

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli, pagination

The below code (search.php) works fine for the first page of pagination only, but when I click on the second page then it shows the following error.

> "Notice: Undefined index: search in /opt/lampp/htdocs/testdb/search.php on line 15"**.

I tried to use $_SESSION also but its not working. The query is passing for the first page of pagination only. I am a beginner in coding. Any help or suggestions will be very helpful. Thanks.

```
<?php        

//Database connection     
$mysqli = NEW MySQLi('localhost','root','','dbname');    

//POST data from the query search page which is to be fetched from Database    
$a=$_POST['search'];// this is line 15 of my code for which the error is appearing      
//PAGINATION          
$rpp = 25;    //records per page       
isset($_GET['page']) ? $page = $_GET['page'] : $page = 0;    
     if($page > 1) {     
           $start = ($page * $rpp) - $rpp;    
}         
 else {        
     $start = 0;    
 }    
//SQL query    
$res =$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE col4 like '$a'");    
$num = $res->num_rows;   
$totalpages = $num / $rpp;        
echo $totalpages;     //to check the no. of  total pages and if it is not whole no. then in the for loop at the end of the code add +1 with $totalpages (i.e. for($x = 1; $x <= $totalpages + 1; $x++))    

$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE col4 like '$a' LIMIT $start, $rpp");      

//Fetch data from table "<table>";
echo "<table>";
while($rows = $res->fetch_assoc()){    
    $a = $rows['col1'];    
    $b = $rows['col2'];    
    $c = $rows['col3'];    
    $d = $rows['col4'];    
    echo "<tr><td>$a</td><td>$b</td><td>$c</td><td>$d</td></tr>";    
}    
echo "</table><p />";    
echo "<div class='pagination'>";    
//make link for next page in pagination

for($x = 1; $x <= $totalpages; $x++)    
{    
    echo "<a href='?page=$x'>$x</a>";     
}     
?>

<!--Below is the HTML code for the search engine:-->    
<html>    
<body>    

<h2>Search page</h2>    

<form action='search.php' method='POST'>    
<input type='text' name='search'></br></br>     

<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'> </br>    
</form>    

</body>    

</html>    

<!--My data has only four columns-->
 <!--sample dataset-->
PtRNAome_1  nuclear     GCA_000001735.2     Arabidopsis thaliana : nuclear
PtRNAome_2  nuclear     GCA_000001735.2     Arabidopsis thaliana : nuclear
PtRNAome_3  nuclear     GCA_000001735.2     Arabidopsis thaliana : nuclear
PtRNAome_4  nuclear     GCA_000001735.2     Arabidopsis thaliana : nuclear
PtRNAome_5  nuclear     GCA_000001735.2     Arabidopsis thaliana : nuclear
```

Comment: I assume your _click on page 2_ is a click on a number which has an `<a>` anchor link right? In that case the page number will be passed as a GET as you have coded. But of course nothing will be POSTed so `$_POST['search']` will not exist as you didnt press the form button

Comment: href is a get method, not a post, so you will not find it, you should pass the search value as well and then you can grab it as a get

Comment: You could save the `search` value in SESSION and then reuse it from there.

Comment: session_start();
$_POST['plant'] = $_SESSION['plant'];
$check = $_POST['plant'];